# How to get a list of check ins using Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to fetch a list of checkins (now a simple post with a location attached) that were made through my app (posting the checkin to a user's timeline works).

Previously, I did it with FQL but Version 2.0 of the API seems to be the last one to support FQL, so I need to fetch the list with Graph.

But I have no idea how to do this and the docs aren't really helpful either (at least to me :( ).

Also, I need to limit the checkins to a range of like 10 miles within the current user's location.

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/location_post/

> By including with=location in the URL parameters, the /home, /feed, and/post connections on the User object can be filtered to just those posts containing a location.

If you have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/feed/#read you can see how you request the posts with a location attached. This is only relative to the current User, so I guess this doesn't help you much.

Furthermore, filtering by lat/lng is not possible via the Graph API.

I'd recommend to use FQL because it will be around for at least another 2 years, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions/#versioning

Comment: 2 years seems to be ok, so I'll go with FQL again then… Thanks!